# Sorting members answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On [TSQL Pivot without aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function)

shahkalpesh answered Aug 27 '09 at 19:17, but his answer is between two answers in 2013....how is that so?

[image]

Comment: Not for me...Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: What sort order are you using?

Comment: I'm using votes tab at the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(When sorting by votes) when posts have the same score the secondary sorting metric is on a randomly generated value (specific to each page load) and not on the posted date, this is to attempt to address the [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) problem.